# Why do two floating-point results differ when they nominally have the same value?

Tags: java, floating-point

I was recently reading about storing floating point values in the memory. And I've written a small program to test what I've read. And I noticed that there is a difference in the way Java processes the floating point values.

```
public class Test
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
     double a = 0.90;
     System.out.println(a);
     System.out.println(2.00-1.10);
   }
 }
```

The above program is printing

```
0.9
0.8999999999999999
```

Why both these statements are not printing the same value? I know some floating values can't be represented exactly. In that case, both should give same value.

Comment: This question was closed inappropriately because it is not an exact duplicate of the question it was marked as an exact duplicate of. The purported original asks about inaccuracies in floating-point representation, but this question asks why two computations with the same mathematical result do not have the same computed result. This property of floating-point behavior is distinct from the inability of floating-point to represent decimal numerals. An opportunity to explain more about how floating-point operates has been lost here.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I disagree. That question is about float vs double, and one of the answers cites IEEE754, which is the answer to this question here.

Comment: @EJP: “IEEE 754” is not the answer to this question. It would not make sense to answer all questions about IEEE 754 floating point with “IEEE 754” or with a link to the specification. Answering a question involves **explaining** and involves explaining **in particular** how the principles involved apply.

Comment: @EJP: Additionally, even if the question is answered elsewhere, the criteria for closing a question as an exact duplicate is not whether the answer exists elsewhere, at the end of a link in some answer to some other question, but whether it is an exact duplicate. This question is not an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When “0.90” is converted to double, the result is .9 plus some small error, e<sub>0</sub>. Thus `a` equals .9+e<sub>0</sub>.

When “1.10” is converted to double, the result is 1.1 plus some small error, e<sub>1</sub>, so the result is 1.1+e<sub>1</sub>.

These two errors, e<sub>0</sub> and e<sub>1</sub>, are generally unrelated to each other. Simply put, different decimal numbers are different distances away from binary floating-point numbers. When you evaluate `2.00-1.10`, the result is 2–(1.1+e<sub>1</sub>) = .9–e<sub>1</sub>. So one of your numbers is .9+e<sub>0</sub>, and the other is .9-e<sub>1</sub>, and there is no reason to expect them to be the same.

(As it happens in this case, e<sub>0</sub> is .00000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625, and e<sub>1</sub> is .000000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625. Also, subtracting 1.1 from 2 introduces no new error, after the conversion of “1.1” to double, by Sterbenz’ Lemma.)

Additional details:

In binary, .9 is **.11100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100** 11001100… The bits in **bold** fit into a double. The trailing bits do not fit, so the number is rounded at that point. That causes a difference between the exact value of .9 and the value of “.9” represented as a double. In binary, 1.1 is **1.00011001100110011001100110011001100110011001** 10011001… Again, the number is rounded. But observe the amount rounding is different. For .9, 1100 1100… was rounded up to 1 0000 0000…, which adds 00110011… at that position. For 1.1, 1001 1001 is rounded up to 1 0000 0000…, which adds 01100110… at that position (and causes a carry in the bold bits). And the two positions are different; 1.1 starts to the left of the radix point, so it looks like this: 1.[*52 bits here*][*place where rounding occurs*]. .9 starts to the right of the radix point, so it looks like this: .[*53 bits here*][*place where rounding occurs*]. So the rounding for 1.1, besides being 01100110… instead of 00110011…, is also doubled because it occurs one bit to the left of the .9 rounding. So you have two effects making e<sub>0</sub> different from e<sub>1</sub>: The trailing bits that were rounded are different, and the place where rounding occurs is different.

Comment: Thanks Eric - could you please explain me about the error? What is this? Why do we get this error value? Is it because we can't get an exact decimal representation for 1.1

Comment: @SanthoshReddyMandadi: I added details to the answer.

Answer (score 8):

> Why both these statements are not printing the same value?

The result is not the same.

> I know some floating values can't be represented exactly.

So you should assume that the result of an operation can depend on the amount of representation error of the values you use.

```
for (long l = 1; l <= 1e16; l *= 10) {
    double a = l + 2;
    double b = l + 1.1;
    System.out.println(a + " - " + b + " is " + (a - b));
}
```

as the value gets larger the representation error increases and gets larger compares with the result of 0.9

```
3.0 - 2.1 is 0.8999999999999999
12.0 - 11.1 is 0.9000000000000004
102.0 - 101.1 is 0.9000000000000057
1002.0 - 1001.1 is 0.8999999999999773
10002.0 - 10001.1 is 0.8999999999996362
100002.0 - 100001.1 is 0.8999999999941792
1000002.0 - 1000001.1 is 0.9000000000232831
1.0000002E7 - 1.00000011E7 is 0.900000000372529
1.00000002E8 - 1.000000011E8 is 0.9000000059604645
1.000000002E9 - 1.0000000011E9 is 0.8999999761581421
1.0000000002E10 - 1.00000000011E10 is 0.8999996185302734
1.00000000002E11 - 1.000000000011E11 is 0.899993896484375
1.000000000002E12 - 1.0000000000011E12 is 0.9000244140625
1.0000000000002E13 - 1.00000000000011E13 is 0.900390625
1.00000000000002E14 - 1.000000000000011E14 is 0.90625
1.000000000000002E15 - 1.0000000000000011E15 is 0.875
1.0000000000000002E16 - 1.0000000000000002E16 is 0.0
```

---

and on the topic of when representation error gets so large your operation does nothing.

```
for (double d = 1; d < Double.MAX_VALUE; d *= 2) {
    if (d == d + 1) {
        System.out.println(d + " + 1 == " + (d + 1));
        break;
    }
}
for (double d = 1; d < Double.MAX_VALUE; d *= 2) {
    if (d == d - 1) {
        System.out.println(d + " - 1 == " + (d - 1));
        break;
    }
}
```

prints

```
9.007199254740992E15 + 1 == 9.007199254740992E15
1.8014398509481984E16 - 1 == 1.8014398509481984E16
```

Comment: I like that the result converges to 0. ;)

Comment: Yes `aLot == aLot + 1`... And `aLotLot == aLotLot + aLot` ;-)

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter didn't like my answer or the tone of it ?!

Answer (score 2):

> I know some floating values can't be represented exactly

Well that is your answer (or more precisely, as pointed out by Mark Byers, some decimal values can't be represented exactly as a double)! Neither 0.9 or 1.1 can be represented as a double so you get rounding errors.

You can check the exact value of the various doubles with BigDecimal:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    double a = 0.9d;
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(a));
    double b = 2d - 1.1d;
    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(2.0d));
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(1.1d));
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(b));
}
```

which outputs:

```
0.9
0.90000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625
0.8999999999999999
2
1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625
0.899999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375
```

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is that, even if 0.9 can't be represented precisely by a `double`, that it should have exactly the same `double` value as 2.0 - 1.1, and so result in the same printed value. That's the error -- this subtraction does not yield the `double` represented by "0.9" (or the exact value 0.9).